# View a PDF in own application

Tags: java, android, pdf

is it possible to view a PDF document in an android application (more or less) easily ? And if so which classes should I use or how can I implement this ? 
Thank you.

Comment: https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/01/04/options-viewing-pdfs.html

Comment: Are you trying to load a local pdf? or a url?

Comment: I'm trying to load a local pdf